# How to create a default binding for a generic interface to a generic implementation with GIN?

Tags: generics, gwt, gwt-gin

I am trying Google GIN for our project and I came across a case where I have a generic interface and a generic implementation of that interface:

```
public interface IFace<T> {
    void setEntry(T t);
}

public class Face<T> implements IFace<T> {
    public void setEntry(T t) {
    }
}
```

Now I have a user of the interface that needs an IFace injected in the constructor:

```
public class IFaceUser {
    private IFace<String> face;

    @Inject
    public IFaceUser(IFace<String> face) {
        this.face = face;
    }
}
```

If I try to bind the interface to the implementation with `bind(IFace.class).to(Face.class);`, the injection fails with

```
Deferred binding result type 'IFace' should not be abstract
```

So GIN doesn't find a binding for `IFace<String>` and falls back to `IFace` use the binding and tries `GWT.create(IFace.class)`.

I also tried `bind(new TypeLiteral<IFace>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<Face>(){});` and `bind(new TypeLiteral<IFace<?>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<Face<?>>(){});` with no success.

I know I could bind `IFace<String>` to `Face<String>`, but that could lead to a huge Module with lots of repeating code in it. It is also possible to use `@ImplementedBy(Face.class)`, but that is not an option.

Is there a magic `bind(...).to(...)` combination I need to use? Is this even possible with GIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is not possible with GIN.

There are several workarounds:

- Let GIN inject an IFace or IFace and then cast to the desired type
- Write a factory for IFace with a Provider injected that performs the cast in a generic factory method. Inject that factory and get a typesafe instance of IFace from the factory.